# 'bower' is not recognized error when doing dnu publish via TFS 2015 On Premises

Tags: tfs, npm, bower, tfs-2015, asp.net5

I'm trying package an Asp.net 5 application using TFS 2015, but it keeps failing saying:

```
'bower' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

The project.json has this section:

```
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [
      "npm install",
      "bower install",
      "gulp clean",
      "gulp min" 
    ]
  }
```

Which makes me believe that `npm install` is getting run before the bower install, but bower isn't working properly. Any ideas?

The command I'm running is:

`dnu publish --runtime active --no-source -o ./published-site`

Answer (score 0):

Some of the ASP.NET 5 templates require Node.js (including npm), Bower, and Git to execute their prepublish steps. Visual Studio comes with a version of these tools, and when dnu/dnx commands are run from within VS, it includes its tools in the PATH environment variable:

```
SET PATH=.\node_modules\.bin;%DevEnvDir%\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External;%PATH%;%DevEnvDir%\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\git
```

If you have VS installed on your build agent, you can set the PATH similarly before you run `dnu publish`. (`%DevEnvDir%` is the location of devenv.exe, typically something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE`) Note that these paths could change in future versions of the Web Tools.

If you can't or don't wish to install VS on your build agent, you will need to install Node.js, Bower, and Git so that they can be found by `dnu publish`.